# Partition cloned disk

Tags: disk-utility, ssd

I cloned a disk with dd on linux and want to be able to use the entire disk, but I'm not sure how as I don't think the OS is recognizing the free space that is unpartitioned. In Disk Utility, I can't select a size larger than 120GB (the size of my old SSD) despite the new one being 250GB.

`diskutil list` output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            119.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

`sudo gpt -r show disk0` output:

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  232762432      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  233172072    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  234441608  253955560
```

Comment: @klanomath Yes... one second

Comment: @klanomath I added the `diskutil list` output. Can you let me know what to do with gpt?

Comment: @klanomath there you go

Comment: The Sec GPT header and table are missing in the output - did you forget to copy them or are they absent? Usually they are in the last 33 blocks of a disk!

Comment: @klanomath nope they are missing from the output...

Comment: @user2544765, Do you still have the original 120 GB drive and does it still function or have you already wiped it?

Comment: @user3439894 I have it still and it's still working yes. Not wpied.

Comment: @user2544765, Then I'd either make a .dmg image of the entire 120 GB drive and restore it to the new drive or use [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) to clone it. `dd` is not necessarily a good way to go in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GUID partition table lacks its backup part: the second GPT header and table.

Your `gpt` output should look like this:

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  232762432      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  233172072    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  234441608  253955527
  488397135         32         Sec GPT table
  488397167          1         Sec GPT header
```

To repair this you have to recreate a new complete GUID partition table.

---

**Preparation:**

- Backup your current Mac
- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive)
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an Apple/Akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (preferably El Capitan or Sierra) or a thumb drive containing a full system (preferably El Capitan or Sierra).

**Repair partition table**

- Open in the menubar Utilities > Terminal and get an overview:

  ```
  diskutil list
  ```

  You will presented with at least 13 disks. Choose the disk identifier of your internal 250 GB disk. Usually this is either disk0 or disk1. Below I assume it's disk0 - use the disk identifier you have found in your environment in the commands below.
- Verify/repair the main disk/main volume:

  ```
  diskutil verifyDisk disk0
  diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2
  ```

  If the disk/volume requires repair use the same commands but replace the prefix verify by repair (e.g. repairDisk)
- Get the partition table:

  ```
  gpt -r show /dev/disk0
  ```
- To modify the partition table of a disk, you have to unmount the main volume and the disk:

  ```
  diskutil umount disk0s2
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  ```
- destroy your current pt and create a new one:

  ```
  gpt destroy /dev/disk0 
  gpt create -f /dev/disk0
  ```
- add all previous partitions (as listed in the gpt list):

  ```
  gpt add -i 1 -b 40 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B /dev/disk0
  gpt add -i 3 -b 233172072 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 232762432 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  ```
- check that the secondary header and table exist:

  ```
  gpt -r show /dev/disk0
  ```

**Resize your main partition**

- Check if the disk identifier is the same:

  ```
  diskutil list
  ```
- Verify/repair the main disk/main volume:

  ```
  diskutil verifyDisk disk0
  diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2
  ```

  If the disk/volume requires repair use the same commands but replace the prefix verify by repair (e.g. repairDisk)
- Resize the second partition with diskutil:

  ```
  diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 100%
  ```
- Verify the resized volume/disk again.

Enter `exit` and quit Terminal. Reboot to your main volume.

Comment: Will this lose data if I don't back up? Only reason I ask is because I won't bother with a backup since I have all of the data already.

Comment: I ran into an issue with my solution and tried yours... it keeps saying that I can't unmount the disk because at least one volume could not be unmounted. forced gives me the same answer

Comment: No... that did fail. it appears that the computer is booting from the recovery partition rather than Internet recovery. is there a way to force Internet recovery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47357/discussion-between-klanomath-and-user2544765).

Comment: Accepting because ultimately this answer led me to my particular solution, which was using everything in this answer except by doing it through a hard drive enclosure and booting from the other drive.

Comment: @user2544765 Hmm did you examine why booting to Internet Recovery Mode failed?

Comment: Ultimately I believe that the Mac in question is too old for that, as no matter how long I held the keys down it always booted from the recovery partition on the disk.

Comment: @user2544765 If I remember correctly Mac models newer than ~2009-2010 should be able to boot to IRM. At least my MBP early 2011 does.

Comment: Could be that this mac is a 2008 MacBook 5,1. Late 2008 aluminum model.